# Executing rule for pair of string and output in snakemake

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, snakemake

I'm trying to learn snakemake and implement a simple workflow:

1. read all the lines from the file
2. for each line execute a shell command
3. redirect output to separate files

I'm running the following snakefile

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

smiles = []
with open(config["smiles_file"]) as f:
    smiles = f.read().splitlines()

rule geometry_from_smiles:
    input: config["smiles_file"]
    output: 
        xyz=expand("results/starting_geometries/{fname}.xyz", fname=[f"{i+1}" for i in range(0, len(smiles))])
    shell:
        "obabel -:'{smiles}' -oxyz -h --gen3D > {output.xyz}"
```

However on the dry run I see

```
obabel -:'c1ccccc1 Oc1ccccc1 Nc1ccccc1' -oxyz -h --gen3D > results/starting_geometries/1.xyz results/starting_geometries/2.xyz results/starting_geometries/3.xyz
```

as a shell command to be executed instead of 3 commands for each pair of input and output

Answer (score 1):

I think the snakemake way of doing this would be something like:

```
smiles = {}
n = 1
with open(config["smiles_file"]) as f:
    for line in f:
        smiles[str(n)] = line.strip()
        n += 1

rule all:
    input:
        expand('results/starting_geometries/{fname}.xyz', fname=smiles.keys()),


rule geometry_from_smiles:
    input:
        fin=lambda wc: smiles[wc.fname],
    output: 
        xyz="results/starting_geometries/{fname}.xyz",
    shell:
        "obabel -:'{input.fin}' -oxyz -h --gen3D > {output.xyz}"
```

That is:

- Create a dictionary linking the input file (the value) to an output label (the key). Here the output label is the incremental number 1, 2, 3, ...
- In rule `geometry_from_smiles` use a function as input to query the dictionary to get the input file corresponding to a given label.

In this way your input files can have any name but the output files will be named whatever you want. That is, you don't need to rely on some naming convention for the input files upon which you may not have control.

As things get more complex, instead of a dictionary you may want to use a pandas dataframe or some other data structure to relate input files to output. For example, if each line of the dataframe is an input file you can have columns contain parameters for the individual rules. Then you use the same logic as above for things like "if input is a.txt get the corresponding row and run this program with the parameters in columns x, y, z".

Comment: I've actually overcame this by making a rule to split multi-line file into multiple one-line files and using keyword `dynamic` in the rule definition. Anyway thank you for the example of good practices in Snakemake, it will be useful for me to learn.

Comment: Note that `dynamic` is deprecated in favour of `checkpoint`. Personally, I find checkpoints tricky to use and I would prefer my solution, if at all suitable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer, but one option is to dynamically define the rule:

```py
configfile: "config.yaml"

smiles = []
with open(config["smiles_file"]) as f:
    smiles = f.read().splitlines()

output_names = [f"results/starting_geometries/{num_smile+1}.xyz" for num_smile, _ in enumerate(smiles, start=1)]

rule_all:
   input: output_names

for smile, output_file in zip(smiles, output_names):
   rule:
       input: smile
       output: output_file
    shell:
        "obabel -:'{input}' -oxyz -h --gen3D > {output}"
```

Note, it should be possible to create a single rule (rather than dynamically create multiple rules), but it would take a bit more time (and possibly additional details) to implement it correctly.